# Firefox console shows error message, Javascript error after installing PHP7

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

my forms aren't working properly since I switched to PHP 7.x
Firefox console show the following error:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data getServerResponse/<@https://www.my-domain.de/Uploads/Templates/folder/Js/jquery.j-pro.js:592:13
j@https://www.my-domain.de/Uploads/Templates/folder/Js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2:29997
g/</k<@https://www.my-domain.de/Uploads/Templates/folder/Js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2:30313
undefined
```

Jquery.j-pro.js shows in line 1  `;(function ( $ ) { "use strict";`

and on line 592 it shows:  `result = $.parseJSON( data );`

I get nuts, because i searching since 2 days for a solution. 
Maybe you guys can help.
Thank you for your effort.

Andrea

PS: here is the jquery.j-pro.js  [jquery.j-pro.js](https://www.file-upload.net/download-13260934/jquery.j-pro.js.html)

Comment: Could you show what the JSON data looks like ?

Comment: Actually  i dont think there is Json data.
I running 2 scripts: jquery-3.2.1,min.js and jquery.j-pro.js
Andrea

Comment: the error says `unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`, I don't ask what you think but what the JSON data actually look like, because your issue probably comes from it.

Comment: Zakaria, I dont know how it looks like, because I not even know where Json data could be or what Json data it is, thats why I said, I think i dont run Json data.

Comment: Zakaria, i have add a link where i posted the jquery.j-pro.js, is it that what you asking for ?

Comment: so, you need to set the debugger so you can see what is in `data`. My guess it it's something downloaded from your server via AJAX, maybe? Since you mention updating your PHP version, I'd guess maybe something is not right in your PHP script and it is no longer generating valid JSON for the JS to read. So first you should check what it _does_ generate, that might give you a clue as to where in the PHP to start looking for issues. You haven't given us much in the way of context about your application though, so we can only speculate really.

Comment: ADyson, thank you for your comment. That was useful. I see in debugger that many files are getting loaded. I thought, just 2 files involved.

In debugger now showing 8 files. But i can go thru these 8 files. 
Thanks alot Adyson..